# How to format datetime without timezone (Z) using moment.js with AM/PM

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

I am converting DateTime to display `YYYY-MM-DD hh: mm a` format using moemntjs in my web application but I do not want momentjs to convert or consider timezone.

This is my date `2018-12-21T15:58:39.35-05:00` returned as part of API and need to display date without (-05:00) in `YYYY-MM-DD hh: mm a` format.

I am currently doing a workaround as below

```
var date1 = '2018-12-21T15:58:39.35-05:00'
var fmtDate = moment.utc(date1).zone("-05:00").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');

$('#output').append(fmtDate);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/73pa1qkz/3/)

Input: '2018-12-21T15:58:39.35-05:00'
Expected Output: '03:58 pm'
But I don't want to hardcode zone (`-05:00`) and moment.js should exclude that in formatting.

Comment: I'm confused, what was the output you were getting and which part of it do you not want?

Comment: what is the expected output? 2018-12-21 03:58pm?

Comment: Sorry for confusion robin looks like content was stripped in editor due to editor,  updated input output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utcOffset` is what you need:

```
var date1 = '2018-12-21T15:58:39.35-05:00'
var m = moment(date1).utcOffset(date1);
var fmtDate = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');

$('#output').append(fmtDate); // result is as you expected: 2018-12-21 03:58 pm
```

here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/73pa1qkz/9/

Comment: Easy to understand.

Comment: That's great Brother. I love your answer. After few days, I found this.